# Set Coolbits on Nvidia GPU without nvidia-xconfig or xorg.conf (Dual GPU AMD/Nvidia system)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, amdgpu, overclocking

My system has 2 GPU's, my main display card, which is AMD, and a compute card, which is Nvidia. I want to overclock or change the fan curve of my Nvidia card without breaking my AMD card - using `nvidia-xconfig` results in it writing the following:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 3090"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Then, I cannot boot up with my AMD GPU, all I see is a grey screen. Is there a way to set coolbits without modifying the xorg.conf so that I cannot boot? I have tried adding coolbits to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf` to no avail. Is it possible to either modify `xorg.conf` so that coolbits is enabled but that the AMD GPU also functions, or alternatively, do this without using `xorg.conf`?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you can use coolbits this way without using a card with X11

Comment: So there's no way to overclock an Nvidia GPU in a dual GPU system? I am using the AMD GPU with x11, so is there a way to modify the xorg.conf so that it would work with the AMD GPU while enabling coolbits? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the only way is xorg?

Comment: Try see if you can remove the second section? https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solved-coolbits-without-xorg-conf/37305/5

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, when I create `nvidia.conf`, I get a gray screen on boot. Dang, maybe this isn't possible. Do I need to write a Device section for my AMD GPU as well maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my xorg.conf with radeon as dual display and nvidia as gpu card:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "radeon"
    Screen 1 "nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "radeon"
    Driver "radeon"
    Option "TearFree" "on"
    BusID "PCI:8:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "radeon"
    Device "radeon"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:6:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
    Option "Coolbits" "12"
EndSection
```

Replace anything taggued "radeon" with your display settings.

Replace the BusIDs with your cards BusIDs with one of the following commands:

```
$ nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info
$ lspci | grep VGA
```

With that configuration, I was unable to set the fan speed for the GPU card through the *nvidia-settings* command.

For that, we have to trick Xorg into thinking a display is connected to the GPU card.

Extract an EDID file (Extended Display Identification Data) from your current monitor and place it in your xorg.conf folder:

```
$ sudo apt install read-edid
$ sudo get-edid -m 0 > edid.bin
```

My final xorg.conf "Screen" config with all the Coolbits you can have and a fake monitor looks like:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
    Option "Coolbits" "28"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
    Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP-0"
    Option "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/edid.bin"
EndSection
```

For more GPUs, add new Screens to the "ServerLayout" section and define pairs of "Device" and "Screen" sections for your additional cards.

Comment: That worked a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, I updated the answer with more info for all our fellow GPU collectors.